# Excel VBA for loop and insert result

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, insert, row

I made a VBA application to extract a result to another sheet if it is satisfied with certain conditions, and insert a blank row, then next extract next result. My VBA only extracts the first result and does not continues, can anyone help?

```
    Option Explicit
    Sub ClearCustomer()

    Dim i As Variant, j As Variant, k As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRow2 As Long
    Dim LastRow3 As Long
    Dim aFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wshell
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim diff As Double
    Const tolerance As Long = 100

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    aFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\FBL5N.XLSX"
         If Len(Dir$(aFile)) > 0 Then
         Kill aFile

    End If

    Set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    wshell.Run Chr(34) & "C:\Users\nxkan\Desktop\AUTO\FBL5N.vbs" & Chr(34), 1, 1

    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\FBL5N.XLSX"

    Set wb = Workbooks("FBL5N.XLSX")

    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ws.Range("A:C,E:F,I:I,L:L").EntireColumn.Delete

    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "FBL5N"

    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("FBL5N")

    LastRow = ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow2 = ws.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow3 = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
              For j = 2 To LastRow2
                          For k = 1 To LastRow3
                          If ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = ws.Cells(j, 7).Value Then
                                             diff = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 6), ws.Cells(i, 6)), ws.Cells(i, 6), ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 4), ws.Cells(i, 4))) + Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 7), ws.Cells(j, 7)), ws.Cells(j, 7), ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 4), ws.Cells(j, 4)))


                        If diff <= tolerance And diff >= -tolerance Then

                        ws1.Cells(k, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
                        ws1.Cells(k, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
                        ws1.Cells(k, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
                        ws1.Cells(k, 4).Value = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value
                        ws1.Cells(k, 5).Value = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
                        ws1.Cells(k, 6).Value = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
                        ws1.Cells(k, 7).Value = ws.Cells(i, 7).Value

                        ws1.Cells(k + 1, 1).Value = ws.Cells(j, 1).Value
                        ws1.Cells(k + 1, 2).Value = ws.Cells(j, 2).Value
                        ws1.Cells(k + 1, 3).Value = ws.Cells(j, 3).Value
                        ws1.Cells(k + 1, 4).Value = ws.Cells(j, 4).Value
                        ws1.Cells(k + 1, 5).Value = ws.Cells(j, 5).Value
                        ws1.Cells(k + 1, 6).Value = ws.Cells(j, 6).Value
                        ws1.Cells(k + 1, 7).Value = ws.Cells(j, 7).Value

                        Exit For
                    End If
                 End If
              k = k + 3
           Next k
       Next j
   Next i

    'With ActiveSheet
            '.AutoFilterMode = False
            '.Range("A1:K1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<>"
    'End With

    MsgBox "Finished"

    End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out the `On Error Resume Next` and see what happens

Comment: @TimWilliams Hi Tim, nothing happened.

Comment: Hard to say what the issue might be without seeing any of your data - maybe only one row meets your criteria? Try adding a breakpoint inside that inner loop and see if it hits.

Comment: Sorry TIm but I don't know how to add...

Comment: add Debug.Print in your code to see what happen (at the begin and the end of each "for to")
track variables "LastRow", "LastRow2", "LastRow3" and "diff" to see values

Comment: @MaximePorté Hi Maxime, I cannot see any difference...

Comment: maybe stupid question, but do you know how to use Debug.Print ?
Is excel return values you expected ? (for variables LastRows and diff)

Comment: @MaximePorté Haha, sorry I don't know.

Comment: (i didn't tought it was so hard to find a "how to" for debug.print)http://solvedstack.com/questions/where-does-vba-debug-print-log-to you
it's where you can see your debug.print

Comment: @MaximePorté It shows 0 for all LastRow and 100 for the diff

Comment: if all LastRow is to 0 after affecting it, you have a problem ;)
begin by correcting the retrieves of LastRows values